# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PhantomJS'

Tags: python, macos, selenium, phantomjs

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PhantomJS'
```

I can't seem to get this to work on OSX.

I installed selenium with `pip install selenium` and I have this version:

```
>>> import selenium
>>> selenium.__version__
'2.21.2'
```

I installed PhantomJS with `port install phantomjs`, and verified that it is the latest:

```
$ phantomjs --version
2.0.0
```

I checked its location is in my `PATH` and my `PYTHONPATH`, restarted my Terminal, etc.,  but this did not fix the error.

`browser = webdriver.Firefox()` works fine.

EDIT:

It seems I was pointing to an old version - `2.21.2` - installed via MacPorts, but I am still unable to correct the problem.

I have got as far as:

```
sudo pip uninstall selenium
sudo port uninstall py-selenium
sudo port uninstall py27-selenium
```

And than I tried to reinstall the latest (2.45.0) from pip:

```
$ sudo pip install selenium
Downloading/unpacking selenium
  Downloading selenium-2.45.0.tar.gz (2.6MB): 2.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/selenium/setup.py) egg_info for package selenium

Installing collected packages: selenium
  Running setup.py install for selenium

Successfully installed selenium
Cleaning up...
```

But now I can't even import selenium:

```
>>> import selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

EDIT 2:

It also appears that pip is pointing to the wrong python. I changed the first line of pip to the correct path, but I'm not sure if this is what I want, and now pip just crashes when I try `pip install selenium`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2671, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 654, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

Comment: '2.21.2' is a very old version of selenium

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed that I am not pointing to the one installed by pip! Investigating some more now...

Answer (score 1):

My problem was `pip` was not pointing to the correct python installation.

First I removed all unwanted selenium installations as described in my "EDIT".

Then I removed pip with `rm /usr/local/bin/pip` and did a fresh install via `sudo port install py27-pip`.

Then I ran `sudo pip install selenium`.

And now everything is working.

```
>>> import selenium
>>> selenium.__version__
'2.45.0'
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>>
```